# Generate uuids for files while using the find command in bash

Tags: bash, shell, find, cygwin, imagemagick

I am having a bit of an issue.
I am searching for some jpg files and using imagemagick to batch-watermark them.

I am running the following command in a cygwin bash shell:

```
find -iname '*.jpg' -execdir convert '{}' -resize 600x600 -fill white \
-undercolor '#00000080' -gravity SouthWest -annotate +0+5 \
$(uuidgen -r | grep -o "\w\{12\}" | tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]') {}-id.jpg \; \
-print
```

The problem I am having is that it seems like the line:

`$(uuidgen -r | grep -o "\w\{12\}" | tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]')`

is being run only once by the **find** command which in turn makes it that all files have exactly the same watermark text which is not my intention.

I also wanted to name all the files after the same watermark text like this by replacing this:

`$(uuidgen -r | grep -o "\w\{12\}" | tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]') {}-id.jpg`

with this:

`wid=$(uuidgen -r | grep -o "\w\{12\}" | tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]') $wid.jpg`

obviously what happens is that if there are 5 files in a folder, 1 would be created and overwritten 5 times, because the uuid is only created once...

What might be the reason why this happens?
Any way for me to fix this?

Comment: Simpler version of the same issue, `find -exec echo $RANDOM \;`

Comment: @BroSlow I can't get that to work with the run-it-with-the-shell fix unless I use a shell file. I tried `find -exec sh -c echo \$RANDOM \;`, but just get blank lines for some reason. Putting `echo $RANDOM` in a file and exec'ing that works, though.

Comment: @ooga You need to quote\escape the entire script to be executed in the subshell `find -exec sh -c 'echo $RANDOM' \;`

Comment: @RaptorX I notice that you tried to edit my answer and that someone (not me!) rejected it. I'll edit it the way you suggested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The entire `find` command is scanned for expansion by the shell before it's executed, and, as you've said, the command expansion is done only once. The easiest thing to do is to make the the entire `-execdir` parameter a shell file and execute it from the `find` command with the shell.

So make a file in your home directory called, say, `watermark.sh`, like this:

```
wid=$(uuidgen -r | grep -o "\w\{12\}" | tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]')
convert "$1" \
  -resize 600x600 \
  -fill white \
  -undercolor '#00000080' \
  -gravity SouthWest \
  -annotate +0+5 $wid \
  $wid.jpg
```

And write your `find` command like this:

```
find -iname '*.jpg' -execdir sh ~/watermark.sh '{}' \;
```

Comment: +1 more readable your way, though alternatively could just surround it with `bash -c` or `sh -c`

Comment: I tried some variants of those commands (even tried with for loops and so on), with this one i have the issue that the find command passes the files with relative paths (i.e. ./file.jpg) and as the watermark.sh file is not in the same dir i get this error:

`sh: ~/watermark.sh ./DSC06940.jpg: No such file or directory`

any way of telling the find command to return full paths instead of relatives?

I will try turning the watermark.sh file in to a function, lets see.

Comment: @ooga nope, that one has the same issue was the original one i posted.

Comment: the command runs well but all files have the same uuid, the expansion happens before the find command as you explained, so in the end after the test, it happens the same as in the original question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56076/discussion-between-raptorx-and-ooga).